# Exclude subdirectories from a bundle; Include-Resource at BND file

Tags: gwt, osgi

Im trying to put a GWT Eclipse project to a Bundle-Jar file.
For that I have to add the war folder to the bundle. The problem is that the GWT compiler add all *.class files in the folder war/WEB-INF/classes. BND try to add all *.class files in the jar file but they are on the wrong path in the project. Thats the problem! Thus I looking for the right Include-Resource: attribute in my BND file.

Is there someone who has an idea who i can exclude special files from a Include-Resource expression.

It works if I delete every time the classes sub folder. But after few second the GWT SDK will generate this classes.

Thanks a lot

Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Please check this: http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#ApacheFelixMavenBundlePlugin%28BND%29-Instructions:

> <Export-Package> ... it is possible to exclude packages using negation by starting
>   the package pattern with '!'. Thus,
>   non-negated patterns indicate which of
>   the available packages to include in
>   the bundle, whereas negated patterns
>   indicate which should not be included
>   in the bundle.

You can also check this project: "http: //bitbucket.org/MikhailKotelnikov/projecttemplate". It is a template for a simple OSGi/GWT application. 
Here I do the compilation/packaging of all GWT-dependent classes as usual but I added the following instructions for the BND tool:

```
DynamicImport-Package: *
Import-Package: *;resolution:=optional
```

In this case BND considers that these packages will be provided by the OSGi environmet at the runtime and it does the job correctly.

Comment: I would actually discourage using those two instructions. DynamicImport-Package will actually let you suck in any package that is available in the framework, and it's really something that should only be used when all other methods fail. Adding resolution is optional to your imports is equally tricky, here you're saying: "hey, I can run with or without these packages, my bundle will deal with that" when I suspect that in your case, if these imports actually cannot be resolved, the code will fail with class not found exceptions.